# Possible to connect pure PHP to SQL Server 2008 Express but impossible with Symfony3

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, symfony

I've read a lot of post on this topic and apply the solution proposed but without success. After installation of PHP drivers, configuration of php.ini, ... I'm now able to connect to the SQL Server with the pure PHP code proposed by the official web site of php as follow:

```
<?php
$serverName = "AMISSAH-PC\SQLEXPRESS"; //serverName\instanceName

// Since UID and PWD are not specified in the $connectionInfo array,
// The connection will be attempted using Windows Authentication.
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"epayzone");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
 echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
 echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

But now in Symfony3, I cannot while I still use the same parameters: as follow:

```
# This file is auto-generated during the composer install
parameters:
database_driver: pdo_sqlsrv
database_host: AMISSAH-PC\SQLEXPRESS
database_port: 1433
database_name: epayzone
database_user: null
database_password: null
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
mailer_user: null
mailer_password: null
secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
```

I get the following error:

```
ConnectionException in AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 103: An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
```

Answer (score 0):

As I am pretty sure you're using Doctrine behind the scenes to connect to your database see this driver documentation for pdo_sqlsrv:

"pdo_sqlsrv: A Microsoft SQL Server driver that uses pdo_sqlsrv PDO Note that this driver caused problems in our tests. Prefer the sqlsrv driver if possible."

Source: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#driver

Comment: Yes I'm using Doctrine and I just realize that I have to remove a line in config.yml under doctrine (pdo_mysql)  and I've done it but now I get a blank page on my app and in CLI I get an error like: 
 [PDOException]
 SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: No
  connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Comment: I download and install the ODBC Driver 11 but still I get the same error

Comment: you should not remove the line but replace it by: database_driver: sqlsrv

Comment: yes ! In fact I already define this parameter in parameteres.yml file as you see it above

Comment: no you don't. you're setting database_driver: **pdo_sqlsrv** and not **sqlsrv**

Comment: I just follow your link and concerning pdo_msqlsrv, doctrine say: " Note that this driver caused problems in our tests. Prefer the sqlsrv driver if possible." and I change the line by driver: sqlsrv but I get an other error: SQLSrvException in SQLSrvException.php line 42: SQLSTATE [IMSSP, -1]: Invalid option  was passed to sqlsrv_connect.

Comment: is amissah-pc your local instance? did you try it without providing the instance SQLEXPRESS (because sometimes for MSSQL this isn't required) - there's definitely an issue with your host/port definition.

Comment: I change the parameter like you said and even try the port with null value but still no success ... in fact I don't understand this error: An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. Because I can connect with this instance name with the pure php code in my post

Comment: can you debug what's happening? still sure there's an issue in this config.

Comment: I've debug it you're right the config were wrong but now I still get this error : SQLSrvException in SQLSrvException.php line 42: SQLSTATE [IMSSP, -1]: Invalid option  was passed to sqlsrv_connect. I dont think this is about configuration

Comment: When you can debug it, check which option is invalid.